# Undefined Reference when compiling with cmake

Tags: c++, c, opencv, cmake, wiringpi

I am working on a project using OpenCV and cmake (both of which I'm new to) and keep getting an undefined reference to functions that are located in external folders.

This is for a Raspberry Pi using a command line interface. My CMakeLists.txt file looks like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED TRUE)
project(projectName)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} project.cpp supportFile.c supportFile2.c)
target_link_libraries(projectName ${OpenCV_LIBS} wiringPi)
```

When I compile with `cmake .` and `make` it completes but with the following message:

```
CMakeFiles/.dir/projectName.cpp.o: In function `main':
projectName.cpp:(.text+0x4c): undefined reference to `initializeBoard()'
projectName.cpp:(.text+0x98): undefined reference to `setRS485ServoPosition(unsigned short, unsigned short, unsigned short)'
```

All of the undefined references are function calls in the supportFile.c, supportFile2.c, or the wiringPi library. I'm not sure how to fix this issue?

project.cpp file:

```
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp" 
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp" 
#include "supportFile.h" 
#include "supportFile2.h" 

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { 

initializeBoard(); brake = 0; speed = 70; usmAngle = 5; value = 4;
setRS485ServoPosition(USM,0,usmAngle); 
setRS485ServoPosition(CAMERASERVO,0,value); 
...
```

The initializeBoard() is found in the supportFile.h file and the setRS485ServoPosition() functions are in the supportFile2.h.

Comment: Are the undefined symbols both from your code?

Comment: These should be implemented in cpp files or libraries not headers.

Comment: Yes. My project.cpp code looks like: (couldn't get code to show in code blocks?)

#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "piBoard.h"
#include "RS485Devices.h"
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

  initializeBoard();

  brake = 0;
  speed = 70;
  usmAngle = 5;
  value = 4;
  setRS485ServoPosition(USM,0,usmAngle);
  setRS485ServoPosition(CAMERASERVO,0,value);
  ...

The initializeBoard() is found in the piBoard.h file and the setRS485...() functions are in the RS485Devices.h.

The piBoard.h includes the wiringPi library.

Comment: sorry, projectName.cpp = project.cpp

Comment: piBoard.h and RS485Devices.h have supporting .c files, which I compiled in cmake with:

add_executable(projectName project.cpp piBoard.c RS485Devices.c).

Would doing each in separate executable and target_link_libraries help?

Comment: Please, do not post a code in the comments - they are not suited for this. Add the code into your question post. You may format added code with `Ctrl+K` or `{}` button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what my problem was. It was not with cmake but with the supportFile.h and supportFile2.h. I made the following changes to both files:

```
// .h file #include and #define section

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

extern // to all .h functions section

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

After doing so, everything compiled and ran.

Comment: `extern` does nothing when applied to function declarations. Just `extern "C"` should be enough.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not familiar with .h files as this is my first time working with them. I just noticed that in the wiringPiSerial.h file it was written with extern for all of the functions.